# Extremely slow issue with mail forms dropdown on self hosted mailing software (Mysql not optimized maybe?)

Tags: mysql, performance, mailing-list

Hope you're well. Absolutely lost on an issue I am having. Created a mailing list with different open source self hosted softwares such as Mautic and Mailwizz. For mailwizz, the Country dropdown basically offers Country/State as the option to choose (ie: United States/Alabama). My issue is, the form is EXTREMELY slow and becomes unresponsive for about 10-15 seconds when clicking the drop down, then trying to go back to enter "Name" "Email" etc. Its not as bad on desktop, but the worst on mobile with android using chrome. It seems like the issue may be Mysql related, but I do have several optimizations on so not sure whats going on. Here is the form: https://marketing.universalenvision.com/index.php/lists/gs453c09q438a/subscribe

Here is my setup. Sorry, not entirely sure how to run queries or know the exact commands for mysql, but know how to log into it and run the command if provided. Not fully a pro with mysql, so any commands or guides would be extremely helpful to get the information that you guys need to help solve this

Latest Plesk 17.8
Latest MariaDB
Latest Centos 6.9
Ram 32gb
Nginx 1.13.8
Latest Php 7.2

Here is my mysql/mariadb configuration from my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
#skip_name_resolve
local-infile=0
#skip-networking
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
tmpdir=/tmp
symbolic-links=0
bind-address=0.0.0.0
max_allowed_packet=500M
binlog-format = MIXED

default-storage-engine         = InnoDB

# BINARY LOGGING #
log-bin                        = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin
expire-logs-days               = 14
sync-binlog                    = 1

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp-table-size                 = 32M
max-heap-table-size            = 32M
query-cache-type               = 1
query-cache-size               = 150M
query-cache-limit              = 4M
query-cache-strip-comments     = 1
max-connections                = 500
thread-cache-size              = 50
open-files-limit               = 65535
table-definition-cache         = 4096
table-open-cache               = 10240
#tmp_table_size                = 64M
#max_heap_table_size            = 64M


# INNODB #
innodb-flush-method            = O_DIRECT
innodb-log-files-in-group      = 2
innodb-log-file-size           = 4G
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 2
innodb-file-per-table          = 1
innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 26G

# LOGGING #
log-error                      = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-error.log
#log-queries-not-using-indexes  = 1
slow-query-log                 = 1
slow-query-log-file            = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-slow.log


[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

I do know I have a lot of countries and state data, which more than likely is the issue here. The software i use has limited options and doesnt offer a (If X then X) option in order to narrow the forms down in sections without extra field entries that arent necessary for one field. Hopefully I can resolve this weird issue soon. Really appreciate the help!

Comment: When you click the dropdown, how many items are you showing? You're saying it's faster on desktop than mobile, which makes be believe it's due to rendering of a lot of items. Since your server is as fast as it is on android as it is on desktop.

Comment: This sort of problem usually is caused by missing indexes or other problems with query performance in the database. It can also be caused by trying to push too much data over the network from the server. Misprovisioned or misconfigured server hardware and software is almost never the problem. Please [edit] your question to show the queries involved in looking up data when you select the country dropdown.

Comment: The best way to see what's wrong with your code is to see your code. Anything less leaves us guessing.

Comment: For optimization questions, please provide the query, `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`, and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.